# How to setup CiviCRM to proper send authenticated (DKIM) emails?

Tags: civievent, email

i want to make sure that all emails send out through CiviCRM have the proper authentication (DKIM). Currently I use (ticket@yogamela.org) as email from address for online event registrations. The same email I created also as mailbox in CiviCRM. But tests show, that the mail is sent with wrong DKIM signature. How to configure it in the right way? 
Is CiviCRM using the mailbox i configured for sending out the email if the email address is the same, or do i need to change anything else?

Mails send directly through using webmail have the proper DKIM signature.

Here the test result if the mail is send through Event Registration in CiviCRM:
https://www.mail-tester.com/test-fp3hn&reloaded=1

Could it be that i have the same problem like described here:
[CiviMail DKIM signature failure](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/25822/civimail-dkim-signature-failure?rq=1)

Or did i just set it up wrong?

UPDATE:

For now i try to setup one authenticated email. Later i may want to add more. In case so can I add them all as Outbount Mails?
Sitegound provides both email hosting and server hosting.

As suggested I setup now an new Outbount Mail using SMTP:
Administer --> Settings - Outbound Mail

ssl://c15801.sgvps.net    (i tried also without ssl://)

465    (i tried also 25 without ssl:// and authentication: no)

Authentication? Yes

ticket@yogamela.org

Then this error comes after clicking save and test:

The site administrator needs to enter a valid 'FROM Email Address' in [Administer CiviCRM » Communications » FROM Email Addresses](/civi/index.php?q=civicrm/admin/domain&action=update&reset=1). The email address used may need to be a valid mail account with your email service provider.

In the FROM Email Addresses I just entered ticket@yogamela.org.

Is my smtp server setup wrong, or my FROM email setup? The email address / password is a valid email with sitegound the port and server (without the ssl:// part) is what siteground recommended to use.

Answer (score 3):

> Is CiviCRM using the mailbox i configured for sending out the email if the email address is the same, or do i need to change anything else

For outbound mail, CiviCRM uses whatever you have configured at **Administer > System Settings > Outbound Email (SMTP/Sendmail)**. How do you have that configured?

From a quick look at the source code of the email you linked to, my best guess is that you have it set up with the `mail()` option, which is likely not going to handle dkim (though that does depend on your webserver set up). If you have SMTP details for tickets@yogamela.org you could choose SMTP option there, add your details and then your SMTP server will then take care of DKIM.

Choosing SMTP and adding your details is likely the simplest route if you want to just get it working. That said, there are a few different ways that outbound mail can be configured so it is hard to give the best advice without knowing a bit more about your set up. Answers to questions like:

- Who provides your email?
- Do you want to email from multiple addresses or just tickets@yogamela.org?

would help provide a better answer.

Depending on your email provider, the SMTP details you have may allow you to send email from any email that ends @yogamela.org. Otherwise, if you want send email from lots of different email addresses ending @yogamela.org, you might want to look at a third party provider like Sparkpost or Sendgrid.

UPDATE:

That error message you pasted is a a bit wrong. The text does not match with the link. The text references FROM Email Addresses (`civicrm/admin/options/from_email_address?reset=1`) but the link you shared points at `/civicrm/admin/domain?action=update&reset=1`. What do you have set in `/civicrm/admin/domain`? (see picture below). Try adding tickets@yogamela.org there.

I suspect it will then work.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your great help! Thx to you Im one step closer to the solution but still encountered some problems with the configuration more in the UPDATE of the question.

Comment: I updated my answer...

Comment: Lets get it working if only in this basic way before exploring other options :)

Comment: PS. I filed a PR to fix this misleading text in core: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/14055/